# Incorrect sum values from MySQL select query

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL Tables table1: INCOME and table2: OUTCOME
And what i have tried so far is wrong because my select query output is incorrect.

This query is output me wrong data (huge amount of sums income and outcome)

Table income:

`| id | date (datetime) | total_amount (int) |`

Table outcome:

`| id | date (datetime) | total_amount (int) |`

```
SELECT
    MONTH(i.date) AS month,  
    SUM(i.total_amount) AS income,
    SUM(o.total_amount) AS outcome
FROM income i 
    INNER JOIN outcome o
WHERE YEAR(i.date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
GROUP BY MONTH(i.date)
```

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` to query them seperately in a subquery and `GROUP` out side

```
SELECT 
  MONTH(d.date) AS month,  
  SUM(IF(d.type=1,d.total_amount,0)) AS income,
  SUM(IF(d.type=-1,d.total_amount,0)) AS outcome
FROM
(
    SELECT total_amount,date,1 as type
    FROM income
    WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT total_amount,date,-1 as type
    FROM outcome
    WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
) as d
GROUP BY MONTH(d.date)
```